# HTTP Post request with binary file body and content type text/csv

Tags: https, power-automate

I need assistance to create an HTTPS Post request in power automate that has content type text/csv and binary body. Below is my Postman call that works and what I've tried to do in Power Automate.

### POSTMAN CALL

This is the HTTP request I am trying to recreate in Power Automate
[image]

[image]

### Power Automate

I am getting the content of the CSV file from OneDrive and then passing the content in the request body
[image]

I also tried converting the file content with the binary expression

[image]

But both approaches give me the same error below and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

"message":"Failed to parse CSV. Nested error is: Too many entries: expected at most 1 (value #1 (11 chars)

This is how the API documentation shows the call should be
[image]

Comment: *that has content type text/csv and binary body* Are you absolutely sure that is right? If something has a content-type of `text/csv` the body should be sent as text, typically UTF8-encoded, line-delimited, with commas on each line to delimit columns.

Comment: Along with the first comment, it's typically quite hard to help when we're kept in the dark about what the endpoint is that you're actually wanting to hit.  We can't read documentation or (if we have the ability to) try it our for ourself.

Comment: I added a snapshot to my original post that shows how the API documentation suggests to make the call, thank you!